# Youtrack Custom field for who raised Issue?

Tags: youtrack

I was expecting this to be a simple thing, but I am not quite sure how to go about doing it.

Basically on the current project we are trialling YouTrack and the agile board is great, but they could do with knowing who raised certain issues in case they need to go question them further on the issue. However I cannot seem to find a simple way to display this information.

I presumed it would be a custom field of type user, but it appears that this would manually need filling in and would not just be able to be pre-populated by the user who is making the task.

So is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you can view only the assigned user's name on a ticket in Agile board.
I've created a task based on your request  http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JT-19118, you are welcome to vote and leave comments.

As a rough workaround, you can configure notifications on created issues in your projects.
In this way, developers will be notified about all created issues and their reporters.
For that, create a saved search (i.e created by: {Testers}), make this search visible to needed group (by clicking "Edit" on the saved search) and enable notification "on issue created" in user's "Profile". Also, user with admin permissions is able to allow this notifications for all needed users by himself(navigate to "Administration" area -> "Users" -> {user} ->"Profile").

Note, that you can receive notifications both via email and jabber.

Thank you.